# issues trying to use Zend_Config_Xml where the heck is it?

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller, frameworks

I am using ZF2 and I want to use Zend_Config_Xml. looking at the library, the directory structure looks like so...

```
Zend/Config/Config.php
```

Then there is

```
Zend/Config/Reader/Xml.php
```

But that does not contain the class either. Where is the Zend_Config_Xml class ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `Zend_Config_Xml` class in ZF2, `Zend_Config_Reader_Xml` is the equivalent. (`Zend_Config_Xml` was a ZF1 thing.)

The docs has usage examples: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.config.reader.html#zend-config-reader-xml